# How do I use ng-click in link call within a directive?

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ry8gkozAaudhlmdPPQie?p=preview

As you can see in that plunkr, I am trying to create a directive which will render different templates depending on presence of attributes on that directive element.

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
<my-dir someparam="true"></my-dir>
```

I am doing this by putting the conditions within the directive's link call like:

```
var str = "";
        if(attr.someparam){
          str = "<button class='btn btn-warning' ng-click='test2()'> Test 2 </button>";
        }else{
          str = "<button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='test1()'> Test 1 </button>";
        }
        el.append(str);
```

I don't want to use `ng-if`, because if the template is not to be rendered, I don't want the html to exist on the page at all.

This seems to be somewhat working, but the `ng-click` calls don't seem to be working at all. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and if there is a better/proper way of doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to compile your html, for you to be able to use the $scope with a dynamically added HTML.

The $compile function will bind your HTML to the $scope. It's a linking function. Without this angular cannot find the directives in your template like ng-click.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vfVeAkGO5VaJd2dWUTWV?p=preview

```
 .directive('myDir', function($compile) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function($scope,el,attr,cntl){
    var str = "";
    if(attr.someparam){
      str = "<button class='btn btn-warning' ng-click=test2()> Test 2 </button>";
    }else{
      str = "<button class='btn btn-primary' ng-click='test1()'> Test 1 </button>";
    }
    var elmnt = $compile(str)($scope);
    el.html(""); // dummy "clear"
    el.append( elmnt );
  }
};
```